# How to create navigation bar in react-native?

Tags: react-native, nav

I'm new to react-native. I want to create nav bar/collapsable dropdown which should contain Home, Blogs, signup, login button/links. On clicking that buttons , it should navigate to respective page.

App.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Blogs } from './app/views/Blogs.js';
 import {Signup } from './app/views/Signup.js;
 import {Login } from './app/views/Login.js;
 import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
 import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
 import { Home } from './app/views/Home.js';

 const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
 {
BlogsRT: {
  screen: Blogs
},
HomeRT: {
  screen: Home
},
SignupRT:{
screen: Signup
} ,
LoginRT:{
screen: Login
},
},
{
initialRouteName: 'HomeRT'
}
);

const MyRoutes = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
 export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <MyRoutes />

);
}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `stackNavigator` please use it in the below code.

```
this.props.navigation.push('BlogsRT',<pass data>)
```

If you are using switchNavigator please use it in the below code.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('BlogsRT')
```

**Note** :- You can write this on your button click event.